# Combining Two MySQL Tables Favoring the Left

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have two rather large tables in a MySQL database with the same columns but different information. I would like to combine them into one new table. The catch is that both tables use a primary key `MasterID` of which there cannot be duplicates. So, I'd like to combine the two tables, and if there are two records with the same `MasterID`, I'd like to use the record from the left table. I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO `new_table`
SELECT * FROM `left_table`
UNION
SELECT * FROM `right_table`
```

But that didn't do the trick. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: ... where MasterID not in (select MasterID from lefttable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `union all` is better than `union`.  Then, you can implement the logic using `not exists`:

```
INSERT INTO `new_table`
    SELECT lt.*
    FROM `left_table` lt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rt.*
    FROM `right_table` rt
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM left_table lt WHERE lt.masterid = rt.masterid);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "lt" and "rt." Should I change those to the names of the tables?

Comment: Replace the names.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
create table left_table(MasterID int, A int);
create table right_table(MasterID int, A int);

insert into left_table values(1,1), (2,2), (3,3);
insert into right_table values(1,10), (2,20), (4,4);

left_table
+----------+------+
| MasterID | A    |
+----------+------+
|        1 |    1 |
|        2 |    2 |
|        3 |    3 |
+----------+------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

right_table

+----------+------+
| MasterID | A    |
+----------+------+
|        1 |   10 |
|        2 |   20 |
|        4 |    4 |
+----------+------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

select left_table.* from left_table
union
(select right_table.* 
 FROM right_table  
 LEFT JOIN left_table ON right_table.MasterID = left_table.MasterID 
 WHERE left_table.MasterID is NULL
);

+----------+------+
| MasterID | A    |
+----------+------+
|        1 |    1 |
|        2 |    2 |
|        3 |    3 |
|        4 |    4 |
+----------+------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: I just realized that email_address is another key in the table. How can I modify this SQL to account for that as well?

Comment: Hi, you don't have to mention the columns. everything is taken care for by the " * "

Comment: Right, but I meant I want the MasterID condition to apply to email_address too. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Hi, not sure I understand. you simply need to add a condition : [...] AND right_table.email = left_table.email